# How to upload file on bucket s3 as readable and not downloadable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to upload sounds on my bucket, with public access.
I made a python script for uploading .wav files. Once I executed it : my problem is the following :

- sometimes I got an url which renders a readable sound (I can listen the sound in my browser without downloading)
- sometimes I got an url which triggers a download

I don't understand why there are 2 behaviors, I want to get only readable sound

Here is my python script :

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).upload_file(KEY, FILENAME, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

There is an example of what I want (readable sound) :
[image]

And an example of what I don't want anymore (downloadable sound) I don't know why, for many sounds, when I click the url it triggers a download:
[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: Add `'ContentType':'audio/x-wav'` to your ExtraArgs, and also note that Chrome caches some metadata, so you'll need to either use a new key or an Incognito browser window to see the change in some cases.

Comment: Seems unlikely that `upload_file()` can yield a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen due to one of below two reasons:

1. The Content-Type of the file you're uploading is `binary/octet-stream` , so while uploading override the Content-Type while uploading the file as below.

[image: S3 Meta Data Example]

2. The browser doesn't support the file type to preview, we can't do it mostly in this case, if the browser is already up to date or else check once by updating the browser.

Comment: I added metada "Sound/mpeg" and got the same result as with  "Binary/octet" , a downlodable

Comment: Seems there is an issue with s3, updating metadata didn't work for me also, instead delete and re-upload the object.

specify metadata while uploading the file itself in Properties section

Comment: FYI I specified `audio/x-wav` Content-Type

Comment: that's curious I don't have this content-type, only audio/mpeg

Comment: Not aware that Sound/mpeg is a valid content type. Also be aware of caching.